# Thumbnail View on Sharepoint 2016 Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, document-library, sharepointdocumentlibrary

is it possible to change view from list to thumbnail on document library sharepoint 2016?

I've searched for documentation on google, youtube, microsoft still can't find the answer, please help. Currently the display of the user is still a list

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using view formatting.
Make sure your library contains 'Type', 'Create by' and 'Type' column.

1.View -> formatting current view -> Prase following code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY0dE.png)

2.Choose layout to 'Gallery'-> save.

code template:

```
{
 "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json Jump ",
 "tileProps": {
 "hideSelection": true,
 "height": "280",
 "width": "300",
 "formatter": {
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
  "align-items": "stretch",
  "margin": "3px 2px",
  "background-color": "#fbfbfb",
  "height": "380px",
  "overflow": "inherit",
  "border-radius": "2px",
  "box-shadow": "0px 1.6px 3.6px 0 #00000024, 0px 0.3px 0.9px 0 #00000024"
  },
  "children": [
  {
   "elmType": "div",
   "style": {
   "display": "flex",
   "flex-wrap": "wrap",
   "position": "relative",
   "padding-bottom": "10px",
   "width": "100%"
   },
   "children": [
   {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
    "margin-top": "0px",
    "height": "200px",
    "display": "block",
    "align-items": "center",
    "justify-content": "center",
    "position": "relative",
    "border-bottom": "1px solid #EEE",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "border-radius": "2px 2px 0 0"
    },
    "children": [
    {
     "elmType": "button",
     "style": {
     "position": "absolute",
     "height": "100%",
     "width": "100%",
     "opacity": "0",
     "cursor": "pointer"
     },
     "customRowAction": {
     "action": "defaultClick"
     }
    },
    {
     "elmType": "div",
     "style": {
     "width": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '', '100px', '100%')",
     "height": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '', '100px', '100%')",
     "oveflow": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '', 'auto', 'hidden')",
     "text-align": "center",
     "overflow": "hidden"
     },
     "children": [
     {
      "elmType": "img",
      "style": {
      "height": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '', '100%', '0'"
      },
      "attributes": {
      "src": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '', 'https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-react-assets/foldericons-fluent/folder-large_frontplate_nopreview.svg Jump ', '')"
      }
     },
     {
      "elmType": "img",
      "style": {
      "display": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '', 'none', '')"
      },
      "attributes": {
      "src": "@thumbnail.383x383"
      }
     }
     ]
    }
    ]
   },
   {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
    "margin": "25px 0 0 0",
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": "153px",
    "width": "100%",
    "color": "#333333"
    },
    "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontSize-14 ms-fontWeight-semibold"
    },
    "children": [
    {
     "elmType": "img",
     "attributes": {
     "src": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'docx', 'https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/assets/item-types-fluent/20/docx.svg?v6 Jump ', if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'xlsx', 'https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/assets/item-types-fluent/20/xlsx.svg?v6 Jump ', if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'pptx', 'https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/assets/item-types-fluent/20/pptx.svg?v6 Jump ', if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'pdf', 'https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/assets/item-types-fluent/20/pdf.svg?v6 Jump ', if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'jpg' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'png' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'gif','https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/assets/item-types-fluent/20/photo.svg?v6 Jump ', if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'mp4' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'avi' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'mov', 'https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/assets/item-types-fluent/20/video.svg?v6 Jump ', if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'zip', 'https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/assets/item-types-fluent/20/zip.svg?v6 Jump ','Unknown')))))))"
     },
     "style": {
     "flex": "none",
     "line-height": "100%",
     "font-weight": "normal",
     "font-size": "2rem",
     "margin": "5px 5px 5px 10px",
     "height": "25px"
     }
    },
    {
     "elmType": "div",
     "txtContent": "[$FileLeafRef]",
     "style": {
     "padding": "0 0 0 16px"
     }
    },
    {
     "elmType": "div",
     "txtContent": "='edited by ' + [$Editor.title]",
     "style": {
     "padding": "0 0 0 16px"
     }
    }
    ]
   }
   ]
  }
  ]
 }
 }
}
```